# groupby python TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < str()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I initially wrote some code in python 2.7, but now I switched to python 3.5.
I want to aggregate numeric data from a couple of columns and grouping by the rest of them or at least one.

Here's my initial dataframe "testdf":

```
testdf
     PROD_TAG   BRAND   Market         ('VAL', 'Per1')  ('VAL', 'Per2')
        P_1       A     Modern Trade         4.3           0.155
        P_2       A     Traditional Trade    5.7           0
        P_3       B     Modern Trade         10.0          11.2
        P_3       B     Traditional Trade    8.7           6.3
        P_4       C     Modern Trade         12.1          12.3
        P_5       D     Modern Trade         8.0           7.0
```

Last two column headers are tuples (thanks captain obvious). Per1 and Per2 stands for respective periods.

I want to execute a line of code, which worked previously on python 2.7:

```
testdf=testdf.groupby(['BRAND'])[('VAL','P1'),('VAL','P2')].sum()
```

It doesn't work because of tuple type of column headers and raises:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < str()
```

Now if I rename column headers like this:

```
testdf.columns=['PROD_TAG', 'BRAND', 'Market', 'VAL-P1', 'VAL-P2']
```

(removing tuples) I'll be able to execute the same line of code with new columns names:

```
testdf1=testdf.groupby(['BRAND'])['VAL-P1','VAL-P2'].sum()
```

and get in the end:

```
BRAND     ('VAL', 'Per1')   ('VAL', 'Per2')
  A            10.0              0.155
  B            18.7              17.5
  C            12.1              12.3
  D            8.0               7.0
```

Most wierd thing here is that if I use `.mean()` instead of `.sum(), min() or .max()`, everything works fine even with tuples.

Can anybody explain me how can I make such aggregations with tuple columns names work on python 3.5?

Comment: I believe this may be a bug.

Comment: Almost a year passed, I forgot about this problem and recalled it recently, just made it to take care of this buggy `pandas` issue by raising on GH issues. But before raising I wanted to check whether it still exists. And it shows up that this issue is not actual anymore=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [`groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and pass a function to aggregate the sum of each group as shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PROD_TAG':["P_1", "P_2", "P_3", "P_3", "P_4", "P_5"],
                   'BRAND':["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"],
                   'Market':["Modern Trade", "Traditional Trade",   \
                   "Modern Trade", "Traditional Trade", "Modern Trade", "Modern Trade"],
                   ('VAL','Per1'):[4.3, 5.7, 10.0, 8.7, 12.1, 8.0],
                   ('VAL','Per2'):[0.155, 0, 11.2, 6.3, 12.3, 7.0]})

type(df[('VAL','Per1')].name)
#<class 'tuple'>

df.groupby(['BRAND'])[('VAL','Per1'), ('VAL','Per2')].agg(lambda x: x.sum())

       (VAL, Per1)  (VAL, Per2)
BRAND                          
A             10.0        0.155
B             18.7       17.500
C             12.1       12.300
D              8.0        7.000
```

Alternatively, the index is not reset and the grouper columns are transformed. So, you could get rid of the *`TypeError`* due to the name mismatch of the columns[`tuple/str`].

```
df.groupby(['BRAND'], as_index=False)[('VAL','Per1'), ('VAL','Per2')].sum()

  BRAND  (VAL, Per1)  (VAL, Per2)
0     A         10.0        0.155
1     B         18.7       17.500
2     C         12.1       12.300
3     D          8.0        7.000
```

But if you [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) the `tuple` columns to `string`, you can continue as before without using `agg` functions:

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={('VAL','Per1'): "('VAL','Per1')",      \
                              ('VAL','Per2'): "('VAL','Per2')"}, inplace=True)

type(df["('VAL','Per1')"].name)
#<class 'str'>

df.groupby(['BRAND'])["('VAL','Per1')","('VAL','Per2')"].sum()

       ('VAL','Per1')  ('VAL','Per2')
BRAND                                
A                10.0           0.155
B                18.7          17.500
C                12.1          12.300
D                 8.0           7.000
```

**Note:** Tested in `Python 3.5`

Comment: Hi man,many thanks for your answer, it really works.
But I still don't get why python "compares" something, I mean tuple() < str().
and the most freaky thing here is that .mean() works! even without .agg() or as_index. 
.max(), .min(), .sum() doesn't, but .mean() does work....
Also strange is that as_index=False helps. It only kicks grouper column from index,how can it "heal" the procedure?

Comment: That is because you are grouping column labels of different types(*one is of str type and the other a tuple*) and using `as_index=True` default in `groupby` which returns object with group labels as the index. As a result, you are basically comparing two different types that leads to the `TypeError`. Hence, it is a usual practice to change the column labels to `str` so that these  erroneous cases can be avoided.

Comment: yep, I got the point that python does compare " two different types that leads to the TypeError".
But I don't understand why it "compares" _column names_...
it's a simple aggregation to sum by brands, what to compare with what?

Comment: Indeed you raised a really valid point. I also couldn't figure out the reason having gone through the *docs/GH* issues. I would suggest you to either post this example in the [`pandas GH issues`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) or maybe create a new post altogether specifying this anomaly and the experts here can guide you in finding the solution.

Comment: ok, I think I'll raise it in GH issues.
Thanks again, Nickil!